# asidownloadcache for post request?

Tags: ios, xcode, asihttprequest

In my iOS app,I'm sending a post request using the asihttprequest methods and receiving json data.
i want to be able to cache the parsed json data if possible (so that i can directly extract and display in the tableview).
asidownloadcache is helpful only if i'm using GET method. So, i'd like to know my options(along with an example if possible)
Thanks a ton for the help, in advance..